# Joomla image slider, built in

Tags: image, joomla, slider

I want to add in my Joomla website an image slider. I can find in google, how to setup just one image per slide, built in option.
Is there an option to have 6 e.g. images per slide?
I dont want to download install any slider plugin.
I want to know if there is a possibility to make a slider what offers Joomla by default.
Thanks!

Comment: When you have a Joomla-specific question, please ask it at Joomla Stack Exchange.  When you post your question, always show your best attempt to self-solve so that it doesn't look like you are deliberately using the community to do your work for free.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't have a built-in slider. However, what you can do is the following:

- Create an article category called "Slides".
- Create your slides as articles and assign them to the category you have just created.
- Create an override to display your articles. That override must contain the code to generate the slides such as [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp).

We like to use overrides instead of using extensions in order to preserve the stability and the security of the sites.